# PHP Array set and loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, null, set

I'm working on a script that will give you information about some Cisco Devices.

```
class COMMAND
{
    ...
    private $intbrief;
    private $core;
    private $allcommand;
    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once 'class.php';
        $this->core = new CLASS();


        $this->allcommand = array(
        array(  "id"    => "brief",
                "def"   => "show ip interface brief | exclude un",
                "vrf"   => false,
                "val"   => "",
        ),
        array(  "id"    => "vrf",
                "def"   => "show ip interface ".$this->intbrief." | include VPN Routing/Forwarding",
                "vrf"   => false,
                "val"   => "",
        ));
    }

    ...

    private function validip($ip)
    {
        // return true or false
    }

    public function go($_ip, $_user, $_pass )
    {
        if($this->validip($_ip))
        {
            $this->ip = $_ip;
            $this->user = $_user;
            $this->pass = $_pass;

            return $this->logic();      
        } else {
            echo "Invalid Options\n";
            exit(1);
        }           
    }


    private function logic()
    {
        foreach ($this->allcommand as $i => &$row)
        {                               
            if(method_exists($this, $row['id']))
            {
                if(!empty($this->intbrief))
                {
                    echo "\n\n\n\t".$this->intbrief."---TRUE\n\n\n";
                }

                if(isset($this->vrf) and $row['vrf'] == true)
                {               
                    $command = $row['def']." vrf ".$this->vrf;
                } else {
                    $command = $row['def'];
                }

                // Send commands to telnet class
                $output = $this->core->GetOutputOf($this->ip, $this->user, $this->pass, $command);


                // Send to parse functions
                $row['val'] = $this->$row['id']($output);

            } else {
                echo "Check functions from allcommand array\n";
                exit(1);
            }   
        }
        return $this->allcommand;   
    }

    private function brief($match)
    {
        // parsing output ...
        $this->intbrief = $output; // e.g. $this->intbrief = "FastEthernet0/1";

    }

    private function vrf($match)
    {
        // parsing output ...
        $this->vrf = $output;
    }
}

$com = new COMMAND();
$f = $com->go($ip, $user, $password);
```

The Loop works just fine, but ...

The array vrf def is `show ip interface | include VPN Routing/Forwarding` - without `$this->intbrief`, because it's null.... But why ? I checked it within the loop...

```
if(!empty($this->intbrief))
{
    echo "\n\n\n\t".$this->intbrief."---TRUE\n\n\n";
}
```

... and its true. So where is the error ?

I want to execute something like `show ip interface FastEthernet0/1 | include VPN ...`

I'll get the information "FastEthernet0/1" from private function brief

Thanks for the Help

cdpb

Comment: how do you init command class

Comment: @onegun

`$com = new COMMAND();
$f = $com->go($ip, $user, $password);`

I'll fix the main code above ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rethink the problems again and tested a bit, i think the problem lies to the array creation. When array create, the variables in array values are parsed and the values are then fixed in this array instance. So i think putting $this->allcommand in the construct or in any other functions does not matter. For solving this problem and not change the structure of your class too much, i would suggest when declaring the array `allcommand` to

```
$this->allcommand = array(
array(  "id"    => "brief",
        "def"   => "show ip interface brief | exclude un",
        "vrf"   => false,
        "val"   => "",
),
array(  "id"    => "vrf",
        "def"   => "show ip interface <inf> | include VPN Routing/Forwarding",
        "vrf"   => false,
        "val"   => "",
));
```

you can then in function logic, after getting `$command = $row['def'];` do a `preg_replace` or `str_replace` to convert `<inf>` if there is any to the value of `$this->intbrief`. Maynot be best solution but is one i can come out.

Answer (score 0):

Nice Idea!

I also tested a bit and build something like a while loop in a seperate function that will only give one part of the array at a time. The idea behind is, that in every round of the loop the variables inside will be set again.

Looks like:

```
    ....

private function arraycommand()
{
    static $i = 1;
    $allcommand = array(
        array(  "id"    => "brief",
                "def"   => "show ip interface brief | exclude un",
                "vrf"   => false,
        ),
        array(  "id"    => "vrf",
                "def"   => "show ip interface ".$this->intbrief." | include VPN Routing/Forwarding",
                "vrf"   => false,
        ),
        );

    while(count($allcommand) >= $i)
    {
        $t = $i -1;
        $i++;
        return $allcommand[$t]; 
    }
    return false;
}

private function logic()
{
    while(true)
    {
        $allcommand = array($this->arraycommand());

        if(!$allcommand[0] == false)
        {
            foreach ($allcommand as $i => &$row)
            {
                ...
            }
        } else break;
    }
    return output
}

....
```

It's not very pretty coded but it works :)

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: that is awesome, glad you sort it out, enjoy coding :)